# Using "proximity" to imply "next to each other"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, expression-choice

I am currently writing the introduction to my thesis and I want to say that two genes are **next to each other**. I would like to use the word "proximity" without saying "close proximity" but am unsure whether it implies the closeness that I want the sentence to.

I have read the thread regarding "close proximity" as a tautology and fear that choosing to use it in my thesis will be considered unsophisticated or be marked as poor language usage.

I have considered using "beside" or "next to" as in "the genes are beside/next to each other" but feel that it is too unsophisticated.

In context, this is what I have:

"Both genes are located on chromosome 1 (for example) and their proximity suggests that both are ..."

I'm open to suggestions other than "proximity" as well.

Comment: You could use "adjacency" instead.

Comment: Both genes are located on chromosome 1; their proximity suggesting that both are ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isolation of cellular DNA sequences that allow expression of
>   **adjacent** genes.

As in the title of this scholarly article from [The Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America](https://www.pnas.org/content/80/8/2117), **adjacent** is used to describe genes next to each other in an experiment.

**adjacent**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/adjacent)

> 1. Close to; lying near
> 2. Next to; adjoining:

Adjacent, meaning adjoined/next to is moore specific than proximity, even close proximity.